# How to get to top of div but not scroll using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the user to the top of a section using jQuery, but NOT by scrolling? For example, I have this bit of code which works -

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });
});
```

But it of course scrolls the user to the top of the section. I want to achieve this without having the visually obvious scrolling effect happen. Any way to have that happen?

Comment: Why do you even need JavaScript involved for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Javascript if you want:

```
<div id="myDiv">Here is some content</div>

<a href="#myDiv">Link to My Div</a>
```